# Compare users from 2 OU and output only when they differs

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I came to you with a big problem.
I'm trying to orchestrate user creation.
Script will look if there is new user within OU_GC that was created in last day.
If it's true I want to compare this user attribute GABCustomUser3 with mail atribute from all users from PL_OU.

If they are the same that means there is no new user to create and I will exit loop.
Problem is I have no clue how to compare them.
Script below returns $properties but with users specified by $user_GC without any comparison and exclusions.

```
$dateforlookup = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$DC_GC = "test1.com"
$DC_PL = "test2.com"

$OU_GC = "some OU1"
$OU_PL = "some OU2"

$user_GC = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_GC -SearchBase $OU_GC -Filter * -Properties GivenName,Surname,GABCustomUser3,whenCreated,Title,Department | Where {$_.whenCreated -gt $dateforlookup}
$user_PL = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_PL -SearchBase $OU_PL -Filter * -Properties mail

if ($user_GC.GABCustomUser3 -ne $user_PL.mail) {

 $output = foreach ($user in $user_GC) {
 
  $properties = @{
    'FirstName' = $user.GivenName
    'LastName' = $user.Surname.Substring(0,1)+($user.Surname.Substring(1).tolower())
    'Email' = $user.GABCustomUser3
    'Department' = $user.Department
    'JobTitle' = $user.Title
    'Organization' = $user.Organization
    'GUID'= ($user.GivenName.ToLower()).Substring(0,1)+'.'+$user.Surname.ToLower()
    }
    New-Object -Type psobject -Property $properties
    $NewUserExists = $true
  }

  Write-Host "New user found"
}
```

Comment: If you set `$user_PL` first, you can do the comparison within your `where` command: `Where {$_.whenCreated -gt $dateforlookup -and $_.GABCustomUser3 -notin $user_PL.mail}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-contains`, `-notcontains`, `-in`, and `-notin` operators allow for comparisons of single values against a collection of values. Performing the comparison while one collection's objects are in the pipeline will make things easier.

```
$user_PL = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_PL -SearchBase $OU_PL -Filter * -Properties mail
$user_GC = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_GC -SearchBase $OU_GC -Filter * -Properties GivenName,Surname,GABCustomUser3,whenCreated,Title,Department |
    Where {$_.whenCreated -gt $dateforlookup -and $_.GABCustomUser3 -notin $user_PL.mail}
```

Now `$user_GC` will only contain objects where `GABCustomUser3` doesn't exist in `$user_PL.mail`.

---

If you want `$user_GC` to contain all users but filter for users later, you may filter at a later time within the code.

```
$user_GC = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_GC -SearchBase $OU_GC -Filter * -Properties GivenName,Surname,GABCustomUser3,whenCreated,Title,Department
$user_PL = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_PL -SearchBase $OU_PL -Filter * -Properties mail
$new_users = $user_GC |
    where {$_.whenCreated -gt $dateforlookup -and $_.GABCustomUser3 -notin $user_PL.mail}
```

Comment: Holly molly, -notin operator just solved everything!
Thank you so much @AdminOfThings

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the filtering should be done with `-Filter` or `-LdapFilter` since that will be resolved by the domain controller and only interesting results will be returned. There's no point in transferring everything only to filter the results out locally. This may have huge performance impact, for my environment it's:

```
> Measure-Command { Get-ADUser -Filter { whenCreated -gt $dateForLookup } }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 15
Milliseconds      : 196
```

vs

```
> Measure-Command { Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties whenCreated | Where-Object { $_.whenCreated -gt $dateForLookup } }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 5
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 181
```

Thus said, I would first get all the newly created users:

```
$user_GC = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_GC -SearchBase $OU_GC -Filter { whenCreated -gt $dateforlookup } -Properties GivenName,Surname,GABCustomUser3,Title,Department
```

Then I would get all the regular users with matching emails:

```
$user_PL = Get-ADUser -Server $DC_PL -SearchBase $OU_PL -LDAPFilter "(|(mail=$([String]::Join(")(mail=", $user_GC.GABCustomUser3))))" -Properties mail
```

Finally I would only take actions on those users that did not match:

```
$user_GC | Where-Object { $_.GABCustomUser3 -notin $user_PL.mail } | { <do whatever needed > }
```

This will make most of the filtering at the source (on the domain controller) and only leave a few records to act on locally. Not to mention huge amounts of data that are now not transferred.

Comment: Thanks @raspy, good point, this is alpha version but I surely must think about optimization of this script. Right now I need to integrate it within SC Orchestrator but I think it's a story for different question.

Comment: @skwierczyk1 Another thing to consider as some of this is good advice is that the `-Filter` value is not a script block. So surrounding it in `{}` is always wrong. It should be quoted instead. The efficiency of using filter is exaggerated here because this person is querying the entire domain. Your code is already targeting a specific OU. It is likely not going to matter *as much*, but the point is still valid.

Comment: I don't quite agree. I made intentional check on the entire domain to show how the big difference can be. This also includes transfer time, being remotely called in through a VPN connection. Actual gain may vary depending on the amount of AD objects of course.

Comment: As for the `-Filter`: using curly braces is not wrong, it is even mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps#parameters): `Note: For String parameter type, PowerShell will cast the filter query to a string while processing the command. (...) if curly braces are used to enclose the filter, the variable should not be quoted at all: Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $UserName}.`